# Create a single row of divs, and add a scroll to their container div

Tags: css

How can I make a set of squares inside of a div line up in a row, and trigger a horizontal scroll when the squares exceed the div width?

This jsfiddle shows gray squares wrapping incorrectly given a narrow width. The gray squares should always be in 1 row, and the container div should have a horizontal scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/anqKb/

**Things I've tried:**

A variety of `position: absolute` and `overflow: scroll` attributes. No combination seems to get the desired effect of a scrollable container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make inline-blocks always stay in one row, use `white-space:nowrap` on container. Optional overflow (i.e. when content width exceeds parent width) is achieved with `overflow:auto`.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anqKb/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Update the css to the following

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anqKb/16/)**.
Change your container class as follows.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another  that contains the squares and set a fixed width.

```
.setWidth {
    width: 740px;
}
```

[www.jsfiddle.net/anqKb/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/anqKb/10/)

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/anqKb/17/ for solution. You needed `white-space: nowrap;` so that each of your boxes don't wrap and continue down the page.

So I added that and `overflow:scroll;` to `.container` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add white-space: nowrap along with that add a width to your container with scroll x visible and y hidden

```
<div class="container">
<div style="width: auto; white-space: nowrap">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
width: 500px;
height: 120px;
background: rgb(100, 100, 100);
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

}

Check : http://jsfiddle.net/anqKb/19/